# iOS - Launch YandexMaps with directions URLScheme

Tags: ios, maps, url-scheme, directions, yandex

**Is there an URL-Scheme for launch the Yandex Maps application with directions?**
I can just launch the Yandex Maps application (if already installed) with few lines of code, but I didn't found documentation about URLSchemes handled by the app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/"];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, as of today this is misleading, there is a URL-scheme to get directions.

yandexmaps://build_route_on_map/?params

Example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://build_route_on_map/?lat_from=59.967870&lon_from=30.242658&lat_to=59.898495&lon_to=30.299559"]];
```

lat_from and lon_from are optional, current position is used when they are not provided.
Don't forget to check if yandex.maps app is installed

```
NSURL *callUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:callUrl])

{
    //Yandex.Maps app is installed

}
```

[Documentation](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-ios-app-docpage/) (in Russian)

Comment: build_route_on_map is used with yandexnavi:// url scheme see https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/navigator/doc/concepts/about-docpage/

Answer (score 7):

There is another Yandex cartographic app, Yandex.Navigator, that **do** support directions. If such a solution is acceptable for you then you can use a scheme like this one:

```
yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_from=55.751802&lon_from=37.586684&lat_to=55.758192&lon_to=37.642817
```

Visit [here](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) for details.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

If you need to open Yandex Navi you can use like this;

1- You should add 'yandexnavi' to info.plist like this;

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>yandexnavi</string>
    </array>
```

2- You should check the app is installed;

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "yandexnavi://")!)
```

3- You should open Yandex Navi with lat & long;

```
let url = URL(string: "yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_to=" + "\(lat)" + "&lon_to=" + "\(long)")

UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not iOS specific but I hope it helps someone looking for Yandex directions URL, as it took me too long to find this. So for a web app I used this

```
https://yandex.ru/maps?rtext=FROM~TO&rtt=auto
```

where either FROM or TO is optional, as well as the `rtt` parameter. So you could use

```
https://yandex.ru/maps?rtext=~Berlin
```

to guide someone from anywhere TO Berlin.

Porting a web app with Google Maps support to Yandex I was looking for an equivalent link for Google Maps directions link `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/FROM/TO` and finally found this on SO. The documentation link from @NKorotkov answer led me here: https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-ios-app-docpage/#buildroute

Answer (score 2):

This works: `"yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_to=" + latvalu + "&lon_to=" + longvalue`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?

You can add parameters like

> yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.5959049,55.7390474&z=12
>   Where ll -> geographic center that will be visible on the screen 
>   z-> is the zoom value

More info are here, but it is in Russian: http://clubs.ya.ru/mobilemaps/replies.xml?item_no=53530

**UPDATE:**
As per site:

> Unfortunately Yandex map app for iOS does not support navigation
>   through URL schemes

Comment: I already know that it is possible pass parameters for zoom (z), center (ll) and location (pt), but I'm looking for directions parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the tech documentation in russian from the [Intents and URL Schemes](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/) section

You will see all url schemes for yandex maps, navi and metro apps.

**[Yandex Maps](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/About-docpage/)**:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://"]]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12"]];
} else {
// Открываем страницу приложения Яндекс.Карты в App Store.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/yandex.maps/id313877526?mt=8"]];
}
```

**[Yandex Navi](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/navigator/doc/concepts/about-docpage/)**:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexnavi://"]]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexnavi://"]];
} else {

// Открывает страницу приложения Яндекс.Навигатор в App Store.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/yandex.navigator/id474500851"]];
}
```

[**Yandex Metro**](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/metro/doc/concepts/ios/yandexmetro-ios-app-docpage/):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmetro://"]]) 
{
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yandexmetro://?alias=moscow"]];
} 
else
{
// Открываем страницу приложения Яндекс.Метро в App Store.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/yandex.maps/id313877526?mt=8"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?pt={0},{1}"
```